# Find byte offset of a pattern in Golang

Tags: go

We can find the byte offset of a pattern from file by
"grep -ob pattern filename";
However, `grep` is not `utf8` safe. 
How do I find byte offset of a pattern in Go? The file is process log, which can be in TB.

This is what I want to get in Go:

```
$ cat fname
hello world
findme
hello 世界
findme again
```

...

```
$ grep -ob findme fname

12:findme
32:findme
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FindAllStringIndex(s string, n int)](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringIndex) returns byte start/finish indexes (i.e., slices) of all successive matches of the expression:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "io/ioutil"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    fname := "C:\\Users\\UserName\\go\\src\\so56798431\\fname"
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }

    re, err := regexp.Compile("findme")
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }
    fmt.Println(re.FindAllStringIndex(string(b), -1))
}
```

Output:

> [[12 18] [32 38]]

Note: I did this on Microsoft Windows, but saved the file in UNIX format (linefeed); if input file saved in Windows format (carriage return & linefeed) the byte offsets would increment to 13 and 35, respectively.

UPDATE: for large files, use [bufio.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner); for example:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    fname, err := os.Open("C:\\Users\\UserName\\go\\src\\so56798431\\fname")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer fname.Close()

    re, err := regexp.Compile("findme")
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(fname)
    bytesRead := 0
    for scanner.Scan() {
        b := scanner.Text()
        //fmt.Println(b)
        results := re.FindAllStringIndex(b, -1)
        for _, result := range results {
            fmt.Println(bytesRead + result[0])
        }
        // account for UNIX EOL marker
        bytesRead += len(b) + 1
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

> 12
>
> 32

Comment: Thanks iokevins! I am sorry I forgot to mention the file is processing logs, which could be in TB. Is there a way to use less memory just like grep?

Comment: @Max Answer updated to show line-by-line streaming scan using bufio.Scanner. Note: By default, Text() returns each line of text, stripped of any trailing end-of-line marker (either LF or CRLF).

Comment: Cool! that is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds great! based on the output, I can use io.seek to read any part of the large file. Is it the best practice?

Comment: @Max Either that or bufio package, which has additional reader helper functions: https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/